# Live calculation for my quickview page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I m developing my own supermarket website, 
i have working live calcuation script took from webiste, if applied in my popup page to do live calculation eg: 1kg rice($200) x 2 quantity = 400$.
this concept applied in this page, its not working.
please send help me on this.
basically i need live calcuating based on quanty and kg selection .

```js
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#size').change(function() {
    updateValues();
});

$('#qty').keyup(function() {
    updateValues();
});

function updateValues(){
    // Remove any previously set values
    $('#show_box, #total_box').empty();
    var qty =  document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var price = 0;
    var rate = 0;    
    $('#size').find('option:selected').each(function() {
        // Check that the attribute exist, so that any unset values won't bother
        if ($(this).attr('data-price')) {             
            price = $(this).data('price');
            rate = price*qty;
            $('#show_box').append('<h6>' + rate + '</h6>');
        }
    });
    $('#total_box').text(rate);
}    </script>
```

```html
<!--==================================
  Quick view modal window
======================================-->

<div id="quick_view" class="modal_window">

 <button class="close arcticmodal-close"></button>

 <div class="clearfix">

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product image column - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  <div class="single_product">

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Image preview container - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <div class="image_preview_container" id="qv_preview">

    <img id="img_zoom" data-zoom-image="images/qv_large_1.JPG" src="images/qv_img_1.jpg" alt="">

   </div><!--/ .image_preview_container-->

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of image preview container - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Prodcut thumbs carousel - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
   
   <div class="product_preview" data-output="#qv_preview">

    <div class="owl_carousel" id="thumbnails">
    
     <img src="images/qv_thumb_1.jpg" data-large-image="images/qv_img_1.jpg" alt="">

     <img src="images/qv_thumb_2.jpg" data-large-image="images/qv_img_2.jpg" alt="">

     <img src="images/qv_thumb_3.jpg" data-large-image="images/qv_img_3.jpg" alt="">

     <img src="images/qv_thumb_4.jpg" data-large-image="images/qv_img_4.jpg" alt="">

    </div><!--/ .owl-carousel-->

   </div><!--/ .product_preview-->
   
   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of prodcut thumbs carousel - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Share - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
   
   <div class="v_centered">

    <span class="title">Share this:</span>

    <div class="addthis_widget_container">
     <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
     <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
     <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
     </div>
     <!-- AddThis Button END -->
    </div>
    
   </div>
   
   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of share - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  </div>

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product image column - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product description column - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  <div class="single_product_description">

   <h3><a href="#">Ivory Body Wash, Original 24 fl oz</a></h3>

   <div class="description_section v_centered">

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product rating - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
   
    <ul class="rating">

     <li class="active"></li>
     <li class="active"></li>
     <li class="active"></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>

    </ul>
     
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product rating - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Reviews menu - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

    <ul class="topbar">

     <li><a href="#">3 Review(s)</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Add Your Review</a></li>

    </ul>

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of reviews menu - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   </div>

   <div class="description_section">

    <table class="product_info">

     <tbody>

      <tr>

       <td>Manufacturer: </td>
       <td><a href="#">Chanel</a></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

       <td>Availability: </td>
       <td><span class="in_stock">in stock</span> 20 item(s)</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

       <td>Product Code: </td>
       <td>PS06</td>

      </tr>

     </tbody>

    </table>

   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="description_section">

    <p>Mauris fermentum dictum magna. Sed laoreet aliquam leo. Ut tellus dolor, dapibus eget, elementum vel, cursus eleifend, elit. Aenean auctor wisi et urna.</p>

   </div>

   <hr>

   <p class="product_price"><s>$9.99</s> <b class="theme_color">$5.99</b></p>

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product size - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <div class="description_section_2 v_centered">
    
    <span class="title">Size:</span>

    <div class="custom_select min">
    <select id="size" >
    <option id="def" value="default" selected>select a course</option>
    <option id="mth" data-price="100" value="1">1 kg</option>
    <option id="eng" data-price="200" value="2">2 kg</option>
    <option id="chm" data-price="300" value="3">3 kg</option>
    <option id="phy" data-price="400" value="4">4 kg</option>
</select>

    </div>

   </div>

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product size - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Quantity - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <div class="description_section_2 v_centered">
    
    <span class="title">Qty:</span>

    <div class="qty min clearfix">

     <button class="theme_button" data-direction="minus">&#45;</button>
      <button class="theme_button" data-direction="minus">&#45;</button>
                <input type="text" value="2" id="qty">
     <button class="theme_button" data-direction="plus">&#43;</button>

   </div>

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of quantity - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product actions - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <div class="buttons_row">

    <button class="button_blue middle_btn">Add to Cart</button>

    <button class="button_dark_grey def_icon_btn middle_btn add_to_wishlist tooltip_container"><span class="tooltip top">Add to Wishlist</span></button>

    <button class="button_dark_grey def_icon_btn middle_btn add_to_compare tooltip_container"><span class="tooltip top">Add to Compare</span></button>

   </div>

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product actions - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  </div>

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product description column - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

 </div>

</div>

<!--==================================
  End quick view modal window
====================================== -->
```

Comment: Where is the php part?

Answer (score 0):

So add the change event to the textbox also.

```
$('#wow, #qty').change(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function with the calcul treatment.
And call the function on specific events for each form element : `change` for select, `keyup` for input text.

```
$('#wow').change(function() {
    updateValues();
});

$('#qty').keyup(function() {
    updateValues();
});

function updateValues(){
    // Remove any previously set values
    $('#show_box, #total_box').empty();
    var qty =  document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var price = 0;
    var rate = 0;    
    $('#wow').find('option:selected').each(function() {
        // Check that the attribute exist, so that any unset values won't bother
        if ($(this).attr('data-price')) {             
            price = $(this).data('price');
            rate = price*qty;
            $('#show_box').append('<h6>' + rate + '</h6>');
        }
    });
    $('#total_box').text(rate);
}
```

EDIT :

After your edit, I have tried to understand your needs. Not sure its what you want but I hope so.

I have made some modifications in HTML (some new ID for HTML elements).

Here is a fiddle to test changes : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/897e0jvr/)

I assume you have a `jQuery` included in your code.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Calculate price on size change
    $(document).on('change', '#size', function() {      
        updateValues();
    });

    //Calcule price on qty change
    $(document).on('keyup', '#qty', function() {
        //If qty is not a number, force default value : 1
        if(true === isNaN($(this).val()))
        {
            $(this).val(1);
        }
        updateValues();
    });

    //Change qty and calculate price when clicking on + or -
    $(document).on('click', '.theme_button', function(){
        var qty = $('#qty').val();

        //Il qty is not a number : default value is 1
        if(true === isNaN(qty))
        {
            qty = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //Check if qty is incremented or decremented
            qty = parseInt(qty);
            if('plus' == $(this).attr('data-direction'))
            {
                qty++;
            }
            else
            {
                qty--;
            }

            //Min value for qty is 1
            if(qty <= 0)
            {
                qty = 1;
            }
        }

        $('#qty').val(qty);
        updateValues();
    });

    //Calculate price for qty and size
    function updateValues(){
        // Remove any previously set values
        $('#product_price').empty();
        var qty =  document.getElementById("qty").value;
        var price = 0;
        var rate = 0;    
        $('#size').find('option:selected').each(function() {
            // Check that the attribute exist, so that any unset values won't bother
            if ($(this).attr('data-price')) {             
                price = $(this).data('price');
                rate = price*qty;               
            }
        });

        $('#product_price').text('$'+rate);
    }
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<p id="product_price">Choose a product</p>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product size - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<div class="description_section_2 v_centered">              
    <span class="title">Size:</span>
    <div class="custom_select min">
        <select id="size" >
            <option id="def" value="default" selected>select a course</option>
            <option id="mth" data-price="100" value="1">1 kg</option>
            <option id="eng" data-price="200" value="2">2 kg</option>
            <option id="chm" data-price="300" value="3">3 kg</option>
            <option id="phy" data-price="400" value="4">4 kg</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product size - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Quantity - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<div class="description_section_2 v_centered">
    <span class="title">Qty:</span>
    <div class="qty min clearfix">
        <button class="theme_button" data-direction="minus">&#45;</button>
        <input type="text" value="2" id="qty">
        <button class="theme_button" data-direction="plus">&#43;</button>
</div>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of quantity - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
```

Comment: thanks for fast reply, its working. also but i applied this coding in my popup page, its not working.. please help on this.<div class="qty min clearfix">
    <button class="theme_button" data-direction="minus" onClick="addcart('+minus+')">&#45;</button>
                <input type="text" value="2" id="qty">
     <button class="theme_button" data-direction="plus" onClick="addcart('+plus+')">&#43;</button>
    </div>

Comment: Can you update your question and create a second part with informations about your coding popup because I cant understand anything in this comment.

Comment: i just re updated my question, please fix on this, would be grate helpfull on this.

Comment: very much thanks for your support, its working but quantity value not showing 1,2,3,vice versa. its appear 1, 10, 20 you can see this in this link http://indyadeal.com/supermarket/Baby+%26+Kids+Care/Baby+Bath/3/1054/0  open quick cart page.